# Could not cast value of type 'Swift.String' (0x10fef45c0) to 'Swift.Error' (0x10ff2bd10). (lldb)

Tags: swift, api, web-services, urlsession

Below line of code is producing the error,

DispatchQueue.main.async {
completion(.success(jsonData), Error as! Error)
}

When print **jsonData** This code returns perfect result of array but getting this error,

Could not cast value of type 'Swift.String' (0x10fef45c0) to 'Swift.Error' (0x10ff2bd10). (lldb)

As the error says I understand its a cast exception, but I'm not able to modify the code to make it work. I'm kinda new to Swift, so any help would be appreciated. Below is my

```
import Foundation

class APIService {
    
    private var dataTask: URLSessionDataTask?
    
    func getPopularPosts(completion: @escaping (Result<Any, Error>, Error) -> Void) {
        
        let popularURL = "URL Here"
        
        guard let url = URL(string: popularURL) else {return}
        
        // Create URL Session - work on the background
        dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            
            // Handle Error
            if let error = error {
                completion(.failure(error), Error.self as! Error)
                print("DataTask error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                // Handle Empty Response
                print("Empty Response")
                return
            }
            print("Response status code: \(response.statusCode)")
            
            guard let data = data else {
                // Handle Empty Data
                print("Empty Data")
                return
            }
            
            do {
                // Parse the data
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let jsonData = try decoder.decode(APIService.self, from: data)
               // print(jsonData)
                // Back to the main thread
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(.success(jsonData), Error as! Error)
                }
            } catch let error {
                completion(.failure(error),error)
            }
            
        }
        dataTask?.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: You completion block should only include a Result.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the completion block parameters, you already are returning the error inside the `Result`'s `.failure(Error)` block so no need to repeat it again as another parameter in the completion parameter.  Here's how you fix this:

Declaration:

```
class APIService {

    private var dataTask: URLSessionDataTask?

    func getPopularPosts(completion: @escaping (Result<CategoriesNewsData, Error>) -> Void) {
        let popularURL = "URL Here"
        guard let url = URL(string: popularURL) else {return}

        // Create URL Session - work on the background
        dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

            // Handle Error
            if let error = error {
                completion(.failure(error))
                print("DataTask error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                // Handle Empty Response
                print("Empty Response") // Throw a custom error here too.
                return
            }
            print("Response status code: \(response.statusCode)")

            guard let data = data else {
                // Handle Empty Data
                print("Empty Data") // Throw a custom error here too.
                return
            }
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let jsonData = try decoder.decode(CategoriesNewsData.self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(.success(jsonData))
                }
            } catch let error {
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }
        dataTask?.resume()
    }
}
```

Calling:

```
service.getPopularPosts { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let categoriesNewsData):
        print(categoriesNewsData)
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
    }
}
```